# Strategy for managing apps and libraries with git and xcode

Tags: ios, git, xcode4

I am looking for some feedback on how to structure my a) Xcode4 directories and b) git hierarchies for apps and their libraries.  I am looking for something that will serve me well when I introduce more libraries and more developers.  My general situation is as follows:

- I am developing two hypothetical iOS applications called, say, MyTwitterApp and MyFacebookApp
- I also have a static library project called MyJSONLibrary that both applications use
- I want to manage all three projects' source control using git (locally for now, but eventually with a master on another central server so I can involve other developers)

One (theoretical) strategy uses the following directory hierarchy where I have a single copy of each project and the workspace for each of the apps would reference their respective MyXXXApp project along with the MyJSONLibrary library:

```
+-- dev/
    +-- workspaces/
    |   +-- MyTwitterApp.xcworkspace
    |   +-- MyFacebookApp.xcworkspace
    +-- projects/
       +-- MyTwitterApp/
       |   +-- .git/
       |   +-- MyTwitterApp.xcodeproj/
       |   +-- (source files)/
       +-- MyFacebookApp/
       |   +-- .git/
       |   +-- MyFacebookApp.xcodeproj/
       |   +-- (source files)/
       +-MyJSONLibrary/
           +-- .git/
           +-- MyJSONLibrary.xcodeproj/
           +-- (source files)/
```

I am not sure, however, whether xcode/git is going to like two different workspaces basically editing the same physical project directory.

Or, alternatively, I could go with something like:

```
+-- dev/
    +-- MyTwitterAppWorkspace/
    |   +-- MyTwitterApp.xcworkspace
    |   +-- MyTwitterApp/
    |   |   +-- .git/
    |   |   +-- MyTwitterApp.xcodeproj/
    |   |   +-- (source files)/
    |   +-MyJSONLibrary/
    |       +-- .git/
    |       +-- MyJSONLibrary.xcodeproj/
    |       +-- (source files)/
    +-- MyFacebookAppWorkspace/
        +-- MyFacebookApp.xcworkspace
        +-- MyFacebookApp/
        |   +-- .git/
        |   +-- MyFacebookApp.xcodeproj/
        |   +-- (source files)/
        +-MyJSONLibrary/
            +-- .git/
            +-- MyJSONLibrary.xcodeproj/
            +-- (source files)/
```

This means that I now have two copies of my MyJSONLibrary project at any given time and probably mandates the use of a centralised git server to coordinate changes made between them both, however it probably gives me a bit more flexibility to manage the two apps depending on different versions of the library.

I've also read that perhaps git sub-modules may be useful, but I am not sure well they work when the library needs to be shared across many apps.

Any thoughts or best-practice guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.
Craig

Answer (score 0):

I generally have copies of all libraries in each project (this applies to everything, not just xcode).

You wouldn't want to update a library to a new version only to have it break all your existing builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) to manage multiple versions of MyJSONLibrary to be used in different Xcode Projects